# how to use a handwritten T shape which is on a body part as the target and paste an image on it?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I am developing a project for my university assignment which has a AR part that I tried to with Unity and Vuforia. I want to get a simple T shape (or any shape which is easy for user to draw on a body part such as hand) as the image target, because I'm developing an app similar to [inkHunter](https://inkhunter.tattoo/). In this app they have got a smiley as the image target and when the customer draws a smiley on the body and places the camera on it, the camera finds that and shows the selected tattoo design on it. I tried it with Vuforia SDK but they give a rating for the image target, so I can't get what I want as the image target. I think using openCV is the right way to do it but it's so hard to learn and I got less time. I think this is not a big thing to implement so please try to help me with this problem. I think you get my idea. in inkHunter even if I draw the target in a sheet also they show the tattoo on it. I need the same which means I need to detect the Drawn target. It would be great if you could help me in this situation. Thanks.

target can be like this,

[image: image target]

I was able to do template matching from pictures and I applied the same to real-time which means I looped through the frames. But it does not seem to be matching the template with frames, And I realized that **found(bookkeeping variable) is always None.**

```
import cv2 as cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils


def main():

    template = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Manthika\\Desktop\\opencvtest\\template.jpg")
    template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)
    (tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow("Template", template)

    windowName = "Something"
    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    else:
        ret = False

    # loop over the frames to find the template
    while ret:
        # load the image, convert it to grayscale, and initialize the
        # bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        found = None

        # loop over the scales of the image
        for scale in np.linspace(0.2, 1.0, 20)[::-1]:
            # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
            # of the ratio of the resizing
            resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
            r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

            # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
            # from the loop
            if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
                break

            # detect edges in the resized, grayscale image and apply template
            # matching to find the template in the image
            edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
            result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
            (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

            # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then update
            # the bookkeeping variable
            if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
                found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)
                print(found)

            # unpack the bookkeeping variable and compute the (x, y) coordinates
            # of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
        print(found)
        if found is None:
            # just show only the frames if the template is not detected
            cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)
        else:
            (_, maxLoc, r) = found
            (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
            (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))

            # draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow(windowName, frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can hint you with the OpenCV part, but without Unity and Vuforia, hope it may help.

So, the way I see the pipeline for the project:

1. Detect location, size, and aspect ratio
2. Use homography for transformation of the image that should be put over the original
3. Overlay put one image on top of the other

I will assume that the target will be a dark "T" on a white piece of paper, and it may appear in different locations of the paper, as well as the paper itself may move.

**1. Detect location, size, and aspect ratio**

Firstly, you need to detect the piece of paper, as you know its color and aspect ration, you may use RGB/HSV thresholding for segmentation. You may also try using Deep/Machine Learning (some similar strategy like in R-CNN, [HOG-SVM](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=histograms%20of%20oriented%20gradients%20for%20human%20detection&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart) etc.), but it will take time. Then, you can use findContours() function from OpenCV to get the largest object. From the contour you can get the location, size, and aspect ratio of the paper.

After that you do the same thing but within the piece of paper and looking for the "T". Here you can use template matching method, just scan the Region Of Interest with predefined mask of different sizes, or just repeat what steps above.

A useful resource may be [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/) credit card characters recognition example. It helped me a lot one day:)

**2. Use homography for transformation of the image that should be put over the original**

After extracting aspect ratio you will know the approximate size and shape that should appear on top of the "T". This will let you to use homograpy for transformation of the image you want to put over "T". [Here](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture16.pdf) is a good point to start, you can also google for some other sources, there should be plenty of them, and as far as I know, OpenCV should have functions for that.

After the transformation, I would recommend you to use interpolation, because there might be some missing pixels afterwards.

**3. Overlay put one image on top of the other**

The last step is just to go through all pixels of the input image and put the transformed image over target pixels.

Hope this helps, good luck!:)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I mean your answer gave me lot of ideas in different ways. The thing is I need to do this process in real time. So realtime template matching will do the trick yeah? And also I want to know how to erase the “T” shape when it gets pasted with an image(a png) on it. Thank you so much you’ve already helped me a lot.

Comment: @thadaBoy you are more than welcome! 1) The speed depends on your implementation and computer parameters. So, if the computer runs fast, you should think about the code efficiency. I think that in this case template matching will be the fastest method. You can also use Numba Python compiler to speed things up 2) For removal of the “T” I would use thresholding result and set all pixels that belong to T to the average of the paper. Check findCintours function and it’s documentation. Good luck!

Comment: thank you so much. I don't know how to thank for this. I'll try this and let you know soon.

Comment: I updated the question, please help me to solve the problem. it seems to be a small problem. @Болат

Comment: it's solved:) problem was because the template resolution was bigger. resizing it solved the probrem.

Comment: @thadaBoy great! Sorry, I couldn’t reach you earlier